# AWS SES Mail Receive And Parsing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

High level AWS solution design:

HTML Formatted mail -> AWS SES -> Inbound Receipt rule -> S3 and SNS -> Lambda function.

The idea being that Lambda would take the SNS Notification and strip out the part with the S3 bucket details - grab the file from S3 and parse it using the mail-parser module.

I have a simple test case which broke out a part of this using a mail which was never in S3 to test the mail parsing component.

Highlighting one specific part of the email as a case in point:-

Before parsing viewing the source within email client looks like this:-

```
<tr class="dataElementContainer">
    <td class="dataLabelContainer">Description</td>
    <td class="dataValueContainer">Text</td>
</tr>
```

When originally coded this would read the mail from a file and parse it.

The output would be in the format:-

```
\n\rDescription      Text\n\r
```

When running another test but this time sending mail into SES and pulling the payload from S3 after it is parsed it ends up in this format:-

```
\n\rDescription \r\n\r\nText\n\r
```

I could regex around it but i'd like to understand whats happening.

\r\n is windows carriage return and linefeed encoding.

Simplified code that gets the S3 object

```
import boto3
import botocore
self.s3client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = self.s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_id,Key=key_id)
```

Simplified code which parse the mail:-

```
import mailparser
import regex

 mp = MailParser()
 parsed_mail = mp.parse_from_string(obj)
 plain_text_body = parsed_mail.text_plain[0]
```

This feels like a unicode/ decoding issue but i cant find out where it might be
Been puzzling over this for a while and i can't quite put my finger on the problem!